# How to fill an array into a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I want to fill my HTML table with my array. I tried it with $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(id);

But it didn't work. I work with sockets so I can't post all of my code that would be too confusing.

I will ads some of my code but it's a general question how to fill a HTML table with input of an two dim array.

```js
socket.on('outputData', function(data) {
      var $rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');
      var resultArray = data.resultArray;
      var name, location, bdate, id, anzahl = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
        name = resultArray[i][0];
        anzahl = anzahl + 1;
     console.log(name);
     location = resultArray[i][1];
     bdate = resultArray[i][2];
     favorit = resultArray[i][3];
     id = resultArray[i][4];
      
     $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(id);
     $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=name]').text(name);
     $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsort]').text(location);
     $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsdatum]').text(bdate);
    }
  $("#table > tbody").append(rowTemplate.html());
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geburtsort</th>
        <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
        <th>Favorit</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You have a total mistake in the code... `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` - Care to fix this?

Comment: I just added a part of my code :/  the code is not important i just want to know how to fill the table

Comment: I am still telling that's a Syntax Error.

Comment: hey do you know which  the unexpectes string is ?

Comment: This: `name "+name+"
        "+anzahl); `

Comment: ohhh that was a console.log and i deleted it :D shit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your variable rowTemplate. Get rid of the $ and it should work.

```
var rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');

rowTemplate.find("[data-id=id]").text("bcd");
```

Test it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwmu4p6q/

I am not quite sure why that is the case, though. I think it is problematic because of jQuery. You can still use variables starting with a dollar sign, but when you start cascading with jQuery functions, it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Another way to do it would be to manually "build up" the row.
Instead of parsing the HTML with jQuery like `rowTemplate = $('...');` and then manipulating it with jQuery selectors you could do it like this with vanilla JavaScript:

```
var outputHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // i for the rows
  var newRow = "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // j for the colums
    newRow += "<td>" + array[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  outputHTML += newRow + "</tr>";
}
```

I would suggest using `let` instead of `var` if possible. And I would argue that this version might perform faster, but the difference, if existent at all, would only matter with really big tables. It depends on the way jQuery selectors and text() has been implemented, though.

EDIT 2:

Check https://jsfiddle.net/Lv9vdv8u/ for the second version.

Comment: is there not an other way to do it? without this scheme?

Comment: yes, you can do it without the "template", if that is what you meant. a way to do so is in my edited answer.

Comment: can you maybe ad a fiddle to your edit?